zooming in smoothly using OpenCV (CV2) and python
I am creating a video from a set of images, by generating each frame of the video using python and CV2 library. It works.
To make the video a bit more dynamic (instead of just a bunch of still pictures coming up one after the other), I've added zoom effect to each picture. I basically do the calculation for each frame about how much zoom I need to apply, and then I resize the frame slightly, using below code.
# Extract the zoomed part of the image using floating-point coordinates
zoomed_image = cv2.resize(current_image[int(y1):int(y2), int(x1):int(x2)], (res_w, res_h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

I'm working with limitation of cv2.resize method, which only accepts integer values for x & y coordinates.
This works fine when I'm applying let's say a 5% zoom to an image that is being displayed for very short period of time. In this case, even if I convert x & y integers, they end up being different for each frame (at 30fps), and next frame ends up being of slightly different dimension compared to the previous frame. The zooming ends up being smooth.
But when the zoom effect is being applied to an image for a longer duration, the integer conversion makes several frames with same x or y or both x & y coordinates same for 3 to 5 frames. That makes the zoom effect choppy.
Is there a better way to resize the image for zooming purpose, where I can use float  values of x & y coordinates that I have computed, instead of converting them to int?
Or if there is a better way to apply the zoom effect in another way to each frame?

Resize first, crop second. Or even better, use an affine transform. See this question.

Read the documentation on resize. It has fx, fy arguments in place of dimensions (set to 0,0) which allow you to provide zoom values that are floats for fractions (rather than percents).

@fmw42 Unfortunately that's only good if you want the origin to be at (0, 0) -- the crop of the input suggest that's not the case here, and it will end up wobbling by fraction of a pixel. It will also get tricky to keep it efficient (memory wise). Whereas doing a transform, it already generates an image of correct size, and lets you set origin to an arbitrary position, all in a single function call.

Right, affine transform would be better. Thanks.

@ChristophRackwitz the thread you suggested does look similar. I'm going through your response in that thread and see if it's applicable to my situation. It does look useful as the OP  of that thread also was facing similar jittering due to rounding. One difference between that thread and mine is, I know why my final output is choppy, OP of the other thread didn't know what was causing the issue.

@kaushal That distinction doesn't matter, if the same solution applies, it's a duplicate. There's nothing gained by having multiple copies of identical answers spread around the site.
